# Stored variable always read as false?

Tags: java, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I have this in my Java class:

```
public class ActionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefs.edit().putBoolean("saved", true).apply();
   }
}
```

And this in my Kotlin class:

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout)

        val prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)
        val saved = prefs.getBoolean("saved", false)

        System.out.println("Saved value: " + saved) // always prints false!
}
```

The last line always prints `false` even when the code in my Java class is called. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getPreferences()` gives you a preferences object that is scoped to the context you called it from (actually just naming it after the class).

Use `getSharedPreferences()` or `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()` to get an object that is shared globally in your app.

Your Kotlin class is currently using `getPreferences()` so it is not looking at the same preferences you're using in your Receiver that you got by name with `getSharedPreferences()`.